# Why is a part of my font blacked out and how can I fix it?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts

I wanted make a custom font which I could use in my app. The bottom right circle should be a **lock**-icon. After finishing it, I used the **Fontself** extension to create a glyph which I could use in my app. The font itself was exported as **.ttf** format. The icon itself is displayed but the bottom right icon looks like this in my app:

I am relatively new to Illustrator and thought I could just create a white circle, put the lock icon onto it to simulate a rounded corner cut this way (or what ever it is called).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TTF fonts can't have different color elements; all fills are going to show up as black.

You have to actually cut out that white circle from the object below using boolean operations (intersect for example) then you have the hollow circle with the arrow on top. Don't use extra colors in your file.

Comment: When I place the object below on top of my clipbaord, how could I achieve the "cut out" effect which I got with the white circle underneath it? Any suggestions?

Comment: @Armin https://helpx.adobe.com/xd/help/combine-mask-objects.html as I said, use the white circle for this operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting me into the right direction. I did it. Wasn´t that hard actually...

Comment: glad to help! :)